# Bootstrap selectpicker refresh works intermittently after set selected val

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap selectpicker for two drop downs in my MVC appmvc-

```
<select id="drpSectorValues" title="Select Sector" name="SectorName" required="required" class="form-control selectpicker show-menu-arrow show-tick"></select>
<select id="drpPractice" title="Select Practice" name="SectorDivisionId" required="required" class="form-control selectpicker show-menu-arrow show-tick"></select>
```

These dropdowns are cascaded from two other dropdowns and the option items are loaded dynamically using jQuery AJAX based on the items loaded in their respective parent drop downs.

```
let $jq = jQuery.noConflict();
loadSectorDropdownValues(parseInt($jq("#drpProjectRegion")[0].selectedIndex + 1));  //works fine
loadPracticeDropdownValues(parseInt($jq("#drpSector")[0].selectedIndex + 1));  //works fine

$jq.when(loadSectorDropdownValues(), loadPracticeDropdownValues()).done(function () {
    //below code is for setting selected item which works intermittently
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#drpSectorValues").val('@Model.SectorName');
        $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
        $("#drpPractice").val(@Model.SectorDivisionId);
        $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
    }, 500);
});
```

The dropdown options are loaded properly through AJAX but I am unable to set the selected item. Sometimes they work and sometimes don't. I don't get any JavaScript errors too.

Can someone please take a look what is wrong with this? Please let me know in case I can provide some details.

Comment: The code in your `setTimeout` function does not make sense. I can only assume this must be an Edit view where you have already selected values for `SectorName` and `SectorDivisionId` in a previous Create or Edit action. If that is the case, then you need to study the code in [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1bPZym) to understand how to generate cascading dropdownlists (you need to bind to you model using `DropDownListFor()`, and the 2nd dropdownlist options are populated based on previously selected values)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes you are right. Unfortunately I couldn't use Razor controls for some reason. I was able to fix this with some changes. Please see my updated code.

Comment: Answers go in the Answer section, not the Question :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Ok, I will add it :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I was using jQuery `when()` function incorrectly. I made the below changes and it works fine now-

```
let $jq = jQuery.noConflict();
var regionId = parseInt($jq("#drpProjectRegion")[0].selectedIndex + 1);
var sectorId = parseInt($jq("#drpSector")[0].selectedIndex + 1);

$jq.when(loadSectorDropdownValues(regionId), loadPracticeDropdownValues(sectorId)).done(function () {
    $("#drpSectorValues").val('@Model.SectorName');
    $("#drpPractice").val(@Model.SectorDivisionId);
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
});
```